# How do I put a cout and a cin on the same line?

Tags: c++, io, cin, cout

I am trying to put a cout and a cin on the same line as so `cout << "Person 1:" << cin >> int p1;`. Does anybody know a way that I could do the same thing successfully?

I'm using C++ on repl.it if that helps

Comment: try a semicolon to separate two different statements - you can put more than one statement on one line (though frequently that makes it difficult to put a breakpoint on the second or later statements, in your debugger).

Comment: I don't understand why there is such a necessity to put it in one line. It's better to write a code that is readable and easier to debug than just saving one more line of code.

Comment: Why?!?!  Are you *trying* to write hard-to-understand code?

Comment: What do you want the code to do?

Answer (score 6):

The code you showed will not work, because you can't pass a `std::istream` (like `std::cin`) to `operator<<` of a `std::ostream` (like `std::cout`).  You need to separate the expressions, separating them by either:

- a semicolon ([Live Demo](https://ideone.com/2trlwn)):

  ```
  int p1;
  cout << "Person 1:";
  cin >> p1;
  ```
- the [comma operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other) ([Live Demo](https://ideone.com/hTVrsl)):

  ```
  int p1;
  cout << "Person 1:", cin >> p1;
  ```

Answer (score 5):

You can write:

```
int p1 = (cin >> (cout << "Person 1: ", p1), p1);
```

This would be a terrible idea in  terms of writing clear code, I'm mainly posting it in response to several others who said that it is not actually possible.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that in a single command/statement.

You need to do it like this:

```
int p1;
cout << "Person 1:";
cin >> p1;
```

Answer (score 0):

All stream operators are return stream objects. `cin` and `cout` are global instance of `istream` and `ostream` classes. When you use `operator<<`/`operator>>`, they are return stream objects to provide chaining.

When you write something like `std::cout << "he" << 11 << 'o'`, it's provide calling `std::cout << "he"` at first (in case of left associativity 
 of `operator<<`). It complete it's code (print "he" on stdout) and return left argument, so now the original line is `std::cout << 11 << 'o'`, then again will call the most left `operator<<` with its args: `std::cout << 11`, on console will `"he11"` now, and the line can be interpreted as `std::cout << 'o'`.

The returning of left arg stream object provide chaining even on your objects. This work the same with input operators. `stream >> x >> y;` mean read from stream `stream` value, store it to `x` then read next value, store it in `y`.

Answer (score 0):

I have no clue why you would want to do it this want to do it this way, but I am still gonna try and answer you.

You can overload the << operator for istream to complete the task, and then use istream's unget() before returning istream, which causes the input to go to both cout and then into the p1 variable. This can be seen in my example code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
istream &operator<<(ostream& out, istream& in){
  int a = 0;
  in >> a;
  out << a;
  in.unget();
  return in;
}

int main()
{
  int p1;
  cout << "Person 1: " << cin >> p1;
  cout << "Test: " <<  p1 << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Please note that this overload is specifically for integers and will not work with other data types. You may see this code in [action here,](https://ideone.com/Wwikxi) but note that the true output is actually

```
Person 1: 5
5Test: 5
```

Comment: Overloading operator where both operands are in `namespace std` means it won't be found by ADL ; it happens to work in this toy program but will fail in a larger program that uses namespaces

Comment: Oh I know, I was showing a way that OP could run the line of code posted in the question. Doesn't mean I recommend doing it like this.

Answer (score 0):

Just press <kbd>space</kbd> instead of <kbd>Enter</kbd>.